# Jupyter reveal based slideshow

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, reveal.js

I want to create a presentation such [this](http://www.slideviper.oquanta.info/tutorial/slideshow_tutorial_slides.html#/) starting from a simple Jupyter notebook.
What I have looks like:

[image]

Given that, I'd expect to get a slideshow with two slides corresponding to the two cells.
Then from the command line I execute:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to slides mynotebook.ipynb --post serve
```

What I get is a static html page that seems to group both of my cells together.

[image]

How do I get the type of one slide per cell effect of the linked presentation?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to include a reference to the reveal.js package in your nbconvert command:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to slides --reveal-prefix="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/reveal.js/2.5.0 mynotebook.ipynb --post serve
```

Or, for instructions on using a local version of reveal.js, see [this blog post by Damian Avila](http://www.damian.oquanta.info/posts/using-a-local-revealjs-library-with-your-ipython-slides.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the generated HTML with your browser?

I had the same issue on a fresh install of Lubuntu in a VirtualBox.  It worked fine (using the `--post serve` flag) on my host system (OSX) but not in the VB.  I didn't find much on the internets, so I just tried loading the XXXX.slides.html file with my browser and that appears to have solved it.

Summary:

```
$ jupyter nbconvert --to slides --reveal-prefix ../reveal.js XXXX.ipynb  # using "--post serve" fails
$ firefox XXXX.slides.html
```

Hope this helps!